# MySQL 5.7 Failed to update target: In aggregated query without GROUP BY this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.7.8rc  Ubuntu 14.04

I have modified the my.cnf to add this line:

```
sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

as I didn't want to just wipe out all the modes.

MySQL has been rebooted.

mysql> select @@sql_mode; returns:
**STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION**

In my SQL client (Navicat), which I have quit and restarted, select @@sql_mode on that connection also returns the above.

However, I am still getting this error:

*MySQL 5.7 Failed to update target: In aggregated query without GROUP BY this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by*

I fail to see how this is possible.

Comment: Workaround is to backup the DB, drop it and recreate it.  See my self answer below.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours of head scratching, rebooting, etc. the only solution I found (*by the tried and true method of throwing crap against the wall to see if it sticks*) was to export the database schema and data (*I did these separately, that probably doesn't matter*), drop the database, recreate it, and reimport the data.  Now I get no complaints.  And yes I verified that the new schema is identical.

It really would be nice to know what the actual deal is, becasue when the current connection says that a mode definitively **isn't** enabled, yet throws an error indicating that the mode **is** enabled, well, that's fairly disconcerting without a decent explanation.